# How to specify Devise 'from' email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want Devise to send emails from specified address, not from ActionMailer default. Is it posible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`config.mailer_sender` property in `config/devise/devise.rb` allows you to specify that. If you don't have `config/devise/devise.rb`, run `devise:install` generator.

Comment: In Rails 3 this has been moved to config/initializers/devise.rb.

Comment: Also remember (for those of you that can't get this to work like I couldn't) that in order to see your changes you have to restart rails server when you edit an initializer.

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 4, set `config.mailer_sender` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` like this:

```
config.mailer_sender = 'Some One <no-reply@example.com>'
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the file is not present , you can create a file at 
 'config/initializers/devise.rb' and add -

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = SUPPORT_EMAIL
end
```